# Windows 10 image with network locations

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, iso-image

Is it possible to create a Windows image with network share locations embedded, so basically when i install Windows 10 on a machine the network drives are already mounted so that i wont need to go in and mount each network drive.

I hope that makes sense?

Thanks,

Comment: You should use "the other way around" by deploying your Drive Letters via AD

Answer (score 1):

If you clone a machine that has network drives mapped, those drive mappings will be bought over into the new machine which is created with the same image. Whether those drive letters resolve to the UNC path then depends on (amongst other things) a successful connection to the domain controller, and appropriate permissions to navigate to the given path.

Comment: You can also automate the mounting of those drives with the appropriate script and/or use a AD group policy.